What fauna can survive a permanently dark sky?
A few days ago I asked this question. In it asked about flora that could survive under a permanently dark sky.
In this regard this regard this question is quite similar. Though now the question is what kind of fauna can survive under these conditions?
Assumptions

Assume an European ecosystems
90% to 98% of sunlight is blocked
Higher frequency = higher block %
Lower frequency = lower block %
The conditions are PERMANENT

Ignore the following

Temperatures differences
Changes to wind and rain
Microbes and ocean life

Established flora
Here is how the flora looks in my world. If you want additional information read the accepted answer in the previous question.

There is a lot of dead biomass
Mushrooms and molds run rampant
There are some low low light plants
Rare spots with dense low light vegetation.

Structure of the Solution
By many solutions
Name what can survive in broad categories and don't focus on individual species.
By a few solutions
Name the individual species that could survive.
By no solution
Just say so, having no possible surviving species is also a valid solution.

Related questions:
Part 1: What flora can survive a permanently dark sky?
Part 3: Living under a permanent dark
Related: Highly resistant House Plant

Approximately how long after the darkening are we talking about?

@g s go with around 150 years of worsening conditions leading eventually to this point.

The olm.

@804b18f832fb419fb142 while i do appreciate your input further clarification would a good think to add to any future answer of yours.

It would depend on how long the plants had to adapt. Quick changes in environment will likely result in mass die offs, but a gradual change (say over 100s of years) would allow some to adapt.

@Martin York the plant had to slowly adjust over about 150 years. Though there was a significant darkening in the beginning there was still a lot of light present.

It might be worth clarifying whether you want to limit the fauna in this question to already extant species, or whether "fast evolution caused by the catastrophe"  is permitted.  The reason for this is that if you permit fast evolution, then the work of Dr David Eagleman suggests new species can and will evolve with alternative sensory mechanisms.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4c1lqFXHvqI  Fast forward to about 2m15s for where it gets interesting.

You have created a new mass extinction, most every dies, only a few small fecund generalists survive by basically pure luck. Just like every mass extinction.

@John That's the point I wanted to archive. I just wanted to know what could stick around.

small fecund generalists, past that its pure luck.

As long as there something to feed on, some fauna can survive.
Look at the black smokers at the bottom of the ocean: the flora thriving on the chemicals emitted by the smokers sustain a good amount of fauna.
In your case you would have fauna feeding on dead biomass, mold and the few plants able to survive in the environment. You will hardly have any megafauna, but invertebrates (worms, insects, slugs, snails...) would surely manage.

Would manage for a while.

@L.Dutch thanks you for your input. While i know it's been a while do you think sone niche selection of bigger animals could potentially manage to survive? Like maybe the size of wolf's or something.

Some thoughts:
If there's an average of 5% of the available solar power, there's a lot less growth and death of plants. Maybe 5% as much, but assuming a linear relationship seems like a risky assumption. This means a lot less calories are available for microbes and animals. This is going to favor small animals over big ones.
By 150 years after the event, almost all of the high-sun plants are probably extinct or almost extinct. Animals that depend on those are probably also extinct, as are animals that depend on those animals. I think there's a lot of cross-over with large animals, here. I'd guess that almost all herbivores bigger than a human are extinct.
Since oceans are unaffected, any land animals that can prey on ocean creatures for most of their calories - including humans - will thrive on coastlines. With human predation greatly diminished by the collapse of the human population in the first decades after the event, fish populations should be back up to their ancient levels by now. Many ocean fish have lots of vitamin D, which means that even dark-skinned humans living in cold places will be okay. Low-light-plant based agriculture will still be possible in such places but yields will be small.
Pale-skinned humans who can synthesize adequate vitamin D from scarce sunlight, living in warm regions where they don't have to wear much clothing, and where the growing season is long and the soil is good, will be able to have a plant-focused diet based on low-light crops.
Large predators which can't get much of their diet from the ocean are probably also almost all extinct.

@g s the oceans being unaffected is not entirely true they are effected differently. I just left out asking how they would be effected to narrow down the scope of the question.

20x as much farmland is unnecessary if they change over to low-light crops.  You bring your northern crops down south and they will make way better use out of what sunlight  they do get as the old crops did.

@nosajimiki good point, will edit

@Fallenspacerock the oceans part is quite crucial. If oceans were unaffected then I agree that the fauna (at least on the larger side) would be dominated by fish eaters... think seals, dolphins, wales, cormorants, sea gulls, fishing eagles, etc. Obviously only on/near water.

@fgysin the oceans are effected differently but they aren't doing to well either. What i had in mind are that they are polluted and full of things that thrive in such water like a certain kind of algae. But assume for the sake of this question that my fauna gains no nourishment from there.

Life requires energy flux. In current ecosystems we're most familiar with, solar energy coming from the sun provides most of that flux. There are niche ecosystems that use other sources of energy. We have been instructed to ignore "temperatures differences", but this is the key to the whole thing. Assuming that temperature is somehow maintained over a significant time period of complete darkness (days, months, years), then there must either be a magical force adding energy to the system at the same rate that Earth is radiating it to the new darkness, or the emission spectra of the Earth must be magically changed drastically. The former obviously provides a source of energy flux for life trivially, and the latter likely does too, depending on the mechanism. So -- the same magic that maintains your temperature, which we are ignoring, can trivially maintain whatever ecosystem you want.

Yes this is essentially how it would work though the exact mechanism aren't fully worked out. That is why i have hardly mentioned them. I n regards to the ecosystem in think it depends on the kind of energy we are talking about. Sure there are beings in my world that use supernatural energy. But this question is about what what creatures would survive with the establishment plant live and what ever eats these herbivores.
